# Getting `this` to work in link-to helper of component

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

I have a component defined like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="assets/images/{{image}}">
    <div class="caption">
      <h5>{{#link-to 'games.game' this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I am using it like so:

```
{{#each model as |game|}}
  {{game-details-small title=game.title image=game.image id=game.id}}
{{/each}}
```

I kind of accidentally got the `link-to` helper to work by passing in `id=game.id` as a property. However, if I remove that the link loses the reference to the id. I'm trying to find documentation on how passing in the id makes `this` reference the id correctly, but I can't find it. Any suggestions, links, or explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `this` inside components, you have to pass the context, in your case you would pass the `game`:

```
{{#each model as |game|}}
  {{game-details-small model=game}}
{{/each}}
```

And the template becomes:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="assets/images/{{model.image}}">
    <div class="caption">
      <h5>{{link-to model.title 'games.game' model.id}}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot.